# sqlalchemy: No class in Base even though primary keys defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database (mysql) that I am reflecting using this paradigm:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydatabase.db")

# produce our own MetaData object
metadata = MetaData()

# we can reflect it ourselves from a database
metadata.reflect(engine)

# we can then produce a set of mappings from this MetaData.
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)

# calling prepare() just sets up mapped classes and relationships.
Base.prepare()

# mapped classes are ready
ExampleThingMapping = Base.classes.exampleThingMapping
print(Base.classes.exampleThingMapping)
```

Example from [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html#generating-mappings-from-an-existing-metadata)

In my database, I have a mapping table `exampleThingMapping` that has two fields:

| Field | Key | FK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| exampleThingId | PRI | exampleThing.id |
| exampleThingGroupId | PRI | exampleThingGroup.id |

I would expect that `Base.classes.exampleThingMapping` would exist and be usable. However, that line leads to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/yhrckiis38w4z4spam28slalkai7cgmq-python3-3.7.12-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 186, in __getattr__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'exampleThingMapping'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_update_sql.py", line 91, in <module>
    utils = Utils(args)
  File "generate_update_sql.py", line 60, in __init__
    print(Base.classes.exampleThingMapping)
  File "/nix/store/yhrckiis38w4z4spam28slalkai7cgmq-python3-3.7.12-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 188, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: exampleThingMapping
```

I originally thought that the issue was because there was not primary key for the table. However, when I described the table after connecting to the database, I found that both fields were marked as primary keys, and also verified that the fields were marked primary in the metadata generated by the reflection. I would expect that I would have an `exampleThingMapping` table in `Base.classes`, but instead there isn't one (all the other tables are present).

**TL;DR**
I have a mapping table with 2 primary keys specified, but no class is being created for the table even though I can see in the metadata that it has 2 primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

When reflecting with [`MetaData.reflect`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect), the `only` keyword argument allows specifying the tables you want to reflect and won't reflect all the tables.

So either you need to remove the `only` limit or you add your table to its list.

```py
metadata.reflect(engine)  # reflect all
# OR
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['exampleThingMapping'])  # reflect only exampleThingMapping
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code wrong. The `only` parameter is not specified in my code (copied from the sample I adapted). I'll update the question to reflect this.